# Reinstalling ubuntu server because of UUID mismatch

Tags: boot, system-installation, raid

I made a media server with raid 5 setup. Since it's a small case I had some of the HDD on the outside.
One of the HDD plugs got pulled out and since then when I boot I get a UUID problem which makes it unable to boot. I tried several solutions that are on this website but none have worked for me.

This is the UUID alert/error I'm getting.

[image: UUID Alert/error]

I gave up hope to fix this issue and I was thinking to just reinstall.

My question is if I reinstall it like this, will any of the data be lost?
I didn't choose to format any of the drives and I'm installing it in the same setup as I did the firs time.

[image: Raid 5 setup]

So can I install it in this way without losing any data of the raid 5 HDDs?

Comment: Does the raid software not format the drives during the setup to make the raid 5 array?

Comment: That's what i am afraid of... But I don't know and can't find a clear answer on the subject.

Comment: All I can offer is my experience, it does format and then make the raid. You need to get precise support on the unstated method of raid you are using. Is it hardware is it software?

Comment: sorry, software raid

Comment: Try to contact the maker of the software.